# Predictive modelling and cost function

Tags: predictive-models

I have to help a company to detect customer in a list of prospects.

The company has this benefit/cost function:

- Value of a new customer = $20
- Acquisition cost = $5

So if the model:

- Miss to detect a customer: it costs $15 *(loss of income)*.
- Predict a non customer as a customer: it costs $5 *(useless acquisition cost)*.

For now I:

1. Use models like Decision tree, Random Forest & Boosted trees and recover the probability of the 2 classes.
2. If: $\Pr(prospect=customer) * 20 -5 > 0$, I recommend to contact the prospect.

### Question

Is there a way to **directly** use the cost function in the model building instead of using simple split criteria like Information Gain, Gini Index, etc.?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if with only 2 classes the cost function has an impact !
Let me know if I should change the example by a problem with 3 classes.